# Google Ads Mob not shown up in preview and production apk's for Expo

Tags: google-mobile-ads, react-native-google-mobile-ads

If the ads not showing in the preview and production apk's but showing in the development build for the expo. Then most probably your Google Ads Mob account is not approved. Please click on the below link to watch a video that How can we easily approve our Google Ads Mob account and successfully able to show ads on preview and production apk's for Expo.
P.S: I have found this solution after 2 days :)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJpOUo2Olfk&t=595s